# How do I use pushd and popd commands?

Tags: shell, cd-command, pushd

What are the practical uses of both `pushd` and `popd` when there is an advantage of using these two commands over `cd` and `cd -`?

**EDIT**: I'm looking for some practical examples of uses for both of these commands or reasons for keeping stack with directories (when you have tab completion, `cd -`, aliases for shortening `cd ..`, etc.).

Answer (score 432, accepted):

[`pushd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html#Directory-Stack-Builtins), [`popd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html#Directory-Stack-Builtins), and [`dirs`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html#Directory-Stack-Builtins) are shell builtins which allow you manipulate the [directory stack](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Directory-Stack.html#The-Directory-Stack). This can be used to change directories but return to the directory from which you came.

### For example

#### start up with the following directories:

```
$ pwd
/home/saml/somedir
$ ls
dir1  dir2  dir3
```

#### pushd to dir1

```
$ pushd dir1
~/somedir/dir1 ~/somedir
$ dirs
~/somedir/dir1 ~/somedir
```

`dirs` command confirms that we have 2 directories on the stack now. `dir1` and the original dir, `somedir`.  **NOTE:** Our "current" directory is `~/somedir/dir1`.

#### pushd to ../dir3 (because we're inside `dir1` now)

```
$ pushd ../dir3
~/somedir/dir3 ~/somedir/dir1 ~/somedir
$ dirs
~/somedir/dir3 ~/somedir/dir1 ~/somedir
$ pwd
/home/saml/somedir/dir3
```

`dirs` shows we have 3 directories in the stack now. `dir3`, `dir1`, and `somedir`. Notice the direction. Every new directory is getting added to the left. When we start popping directories off, they'll come from the left as well.

#### manually change directories to `../dir2`

```
$ cd ../dir2
$ pwd
/home/saml/somedir/dir2
$ dirs
~/somedir/dir2 ~/somedir/dir1 ~/somedir
```

#### Now start popping directories

```
$ popd
~/somedir/dir1 ~/somedir
$ pwd
/home/saml/somedir/dir1
```

Notice we popped back to `dir1`.

#### Pop again...

```
$ popd
~/somedir    
$ pwd
/home/saml/somedir
```

And we're back where we started, `somedir`.

Might get a little confusing, but the head of the stack is the directory that you're currently in. Hence when we get back to `somedir`, even though `dirs` shows this:

```
$ dirs
~/somedir
```

Our stack is in fact empty.

```
$ popd
bash: popd: directory stack empty
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally understand the concept of stack and how this commands work. However, I'm looking for some practical reasons for keeping stack with directories (when you have tab completion, `cd -`, aliases for shortening `cd ..`, etc.).

Comment: I often use `pushd` & `popd` in scripts b/c they save me from having to remember where I was coming from, I can always just `popd` to get back from where I came. I usually do `popd >/dev/null 2>&1` to make it silent. I use cd- everyday in my shell. There are some other time saving tips in this article as well: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/6-awesome-linux-cd-command-hacks-productivity-tip3-for-geeks/.

Comment: Take a look at `$CDPATH`. It's pretty powerful if you're looking for more efficient ways to get around via cd.

Comment: @slm, is there any advantage to using `popd >/dev/null 2>&1` in a script rather than `cd - >/dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: @Garrett - none that I can conceive.

Comment: @Garrett @slm since `cd -` only tracks the last directory, i imagine it would be possible to have issues if you call a function which also changes directory internally.  in that case, the function would end up resetting - to your current directory, not the directory you want to pop back to.  pushd/popd is the safest method.  Note: i haven't tested my theory.

Comment: Why not going back to `~/somedir/dir3` after the first `popd`?

Comment: @BinaryPhile wouldn't you have the same issue then if this hypothetical function you called also modified the directory stack?

Comment: Can I also `jumpd` to a dir on the stack by index or something ?

Comment: What is the purpose of the _manually change directories to ../dir2_ section? - anyway valuable explanation

Answer (score 260):

There is **a really useful use case for `pushd` and `popd`commands** for working with several folders simultaneously.

You can navigate the stack very easily, since it is enumerated.
Meaning, you can have several working folders at your disposal during work.

**See a simple example below.**

---

First, let's create example folder structure.

```
    user@vb:~$ mkdir navigate
    user@vb:~/navigate$ mkdir dir1
    user@vb:~/navigate$ mkdir dir2
    user@vb:~/navigate$ mkdir dir3
```

Then you can add all your folders to the stack:

```
    user@vb:~/navigate$ pushd dir1/
    ~/navigate/dir1 ~/navigate
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir1$ pushd ../dir2/
    ~/navigate/dir2 ~/navigate/dir1 ~/navigate
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir2$ pushd ../dir3/
    ~/navigate/dir3 ~/navigate/dir2 ~/navigate/dir1 ~/navigate
```

You can look it up by:

```
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir3$ dirs -v
     0  ~/navigate/dir3
     1  ~/navigate/dir2
     2  ~/navigate/dir1
     3  ~/navigate
```

To navigate safely, you need to add the last (zero) folder twice, since it will be always rewritten:

```
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir3$ pushd .
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir3$ dirs -v
     0  ~/navigate/dir3
     1  ~/navigate/dir3
     2  ~/navigate/dir2
     3  ~/navigate/dir1
     4  ~/navigate
```

Now, you can jump around through these folders and work with stack as with aliases for the folders. I guess the following part is self explanatory:

```
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir3$ cd ~4
    user@vb:~/navigate$ dirs -v
     0  ~/navigate
     1  ~/navigate/dir3
     2  ~/navigate/dir2
     3  ~/navigate/dir1
     4  ~/navigate
    user@vb:~/navigate$ cd ~3
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir1$ dirs -v
     0  ~/navigate/dir1
     1  ~/navigate/dir3
     2  ~/navigate/dir2
     3  ~/navigate/dir1
     4  ~/navigate
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir1$ touch text.txt
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir1$ cp text.txt ~2
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir1$ ls ~2
    text.txt
    user@vb:~/navigate/dir1$ dirs -v
     0  ~/navigate/dir1
     1  ~/navigate/dir3
     2  ~/navigate/dir2
     3  ~/navigate/dir1
     4  ~/navigate
```

---

**Additional tip** is to create some alias for `dirs -v`.

For example:

```
# In ~/.bashrc
alias dirs="dirs -v"
```

Comment: And you can clear the stack by ```dirs -c```

Comment: +1 for actually giving some practical examples. It's easy to see what pushd/popd do from the man page, but dirs and cd ~# are not obvious at first.

Comment: you could also use a solution like fasd for this kind of workflow instead, though

Comment: so its better for a more transient use case than setting a CDPATH?

Comment: what if the path contains spaces? `ls "~2"` is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Jun, there's "mkdir dir{1,2,3}" to create 3 directories in one shot.

Comment: @BulatM. in that case you could even go one step further: ```mkdir -p navigate/dir{1,2,3}``` that will create the base dir at the same time

Comment: I learned about `cd ~#` from this answer. Although I read the official documentation for `dirs`, I did not find any clue regarding this useful feature there.  Where would I have to look for official documentation of this feature?

Answer (score 62):

One simple use case for using dirs stack what you cannot do by just cd is:

`pushd .` adds current directory XX to `dirs` stack. Afterwards, you can move around using `cd`, and to return to XX you just do `popd` regardless of how "far away" are you in the directory tree (can jump over multiple levels, sideways etc). Especially useful in bash scripts.

Comment: I think this is the feature I take advantage of most often. Because `pushd`/`popd` work independent from `cd`, you can use them as a more stable bookmark than `cd -`.

Comment: for me this is not true. Every time i use cd my stack changes.

Comment: oh that was coz of using zsh, when I change to bash, it works fine

Comment: This is the only substantive answer as regards a comparison with cd -, IMO. As to whether pushd foo; <random dir changing>; popd is more worthwhile than a=foo; cd $a; <random dir changing>; cd $a ... For scripts I can see a tiny syntactic convenience in the former (pushd), but a massive improvement in clarity in the latter ([explicit] variables!). For an interactive session, I think I would just assume have my directory hierarchy organized properly in the first place, and if I got lost simply cd ~/back/to/obvious/path.

Comment: @HarendraSingh you don't happen to have `AUTO_PUSHD` set? It will make `cd` behave like `pushd`, unset it and you'll be back to "normal behaviour".

Comment: For those using [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto) for zsh, the `'directory'` module sets `AUTO_PUSHD`, sneakily. You can comment that out here: `~/.zprezto/modules/directory/init.zsh`

Answer (score 19):

The pushd/popd is such a simple concept which took me awhile to comprehend since people tend to teach it by defining these commands as commands that 'manipulate the directory stack' which in my opinion is very confusing.

I look at it in a different way:

**pushd [folder_name]** - will cd into [folder_name] and will **document** the destination which is [folder_name] in a dir-stack.
While the top directory in the stack will always be the current dir you are in.

**popd** - will cd into the **directory record** which is **documented** at the top of the stack and then remove the documentation (from the dir-stack).

**dirs** - Will print the dir-stack (which can be treated as the dir Db where the leftmost entry is the current directory (top of the stack).

**So the 2 most popular use cases are:**

**Use case 1:** Navigating using pushd and popd

```
root@mypc:/main/$ ls
dir1  dir2  dir3  dir4

root@mypc:/main/$ dirs   # prints the current stack
/main

root@mypc:/main/$ pushd dir1    # Will cd to dir1 and document dir1 in dir stack, stack is now:
/main/dir1 /main 
root@mypc:/main/dir1$    # I am now in /main/dir1

root@mypc:/main/dir1$    # Now let's go wild and document whatever I want
root@mypc:/main/dir1$ pushd ../dir2 
root@mypc:/main/dir2$     # Woo I am in /main/dir2
root@mypc:/main/dir2$ pushd ../dir3 
root@mypc:/main/dir3$     # Woo I am in /main/dir3
root@mypc:/main/dir3$ pushd ../dir4 
root@mypc:/main/dir4$     # Woo I am in /main/dir4
root@mypc:/main/dir4$ dirs   # Now dir stack is:
/main/dir4 /main/dir3 /main/dir2 /main/dir1 /main
```

I did the above since I would like to navigate back to those folders I documented! (using popd, instead of typing the relative or absolute path of each dir I want to go back into).

Note that if I manually cd, I will affect the top dir stack entry (which is always the current dir)

```
root@mypc:/main/dir4$ cd ..   # Now dir stack is:
# (note that /main appear in the leftmost as well which is the top of the stack)
/main /main/dir3 /main/dir2 /main/dir1 /main
root@mypc:/main$
```

Let's navigate backwards now:

```
root@mypc:/main$ popd
root@mypc:/main$     # Still in /main since it was at the top of the dir stack
root@mypc:/main$ dirs    # Stack is now:
/main/dir3 /main/dir2 /main/dir1 /main

root@mypc:/main$ popd
root@mypc:/main/dir3$ popd    # Woo in dir3 now, about to navigate to dir2
root@mypc:/main/dir2$ popd    # Woo in dir2, about to navigate to dir1
root@mypc:/main/dir1$ dirs    # Stack is now:
/main
```

Again I can document whatever dir I want and then navigate manually to another dir then I will be able to easily return to the documented dir I inserted to the stack.

**Use case 2:** Navigating using numeric stack index

Lets say I pushed using pushd dir4 dir3 dir2 dir1, now running dir -v will show:

```
root@mypc:/main$ dirs -v
 0  /main/dir1  (this is the current dir you are in always)
 1  /main/dir2
 2  /main/dir3
 3  /main/dir4
```

Now you can do any Linux operation which involves directories using the stack index:

```
root@mypc:/main$ cp ~2/temp.txt ~3/new_temp.txt    # this will run in the background, something like:
# cp /main/dir2/temp.txt  /main/dir3/new_temp.txt
```

You can even delete a specific entry from the dir-stack:

```
root@mypc:/main$ popd ~4
```

Hope that using the words **"documenting"** or thinking about the dir-stack as some kind of Db simplifies the concept!

Comment: Actually, `pushd` doesn’t document the destination directory; it documents the directory you *were* in when you issued the command. Try `cd dir1; pd dir2; pd dir3; pd dir4; cd dir5` and then run `dirs`. It’s confusing because the `dirs` command shows the current directory as the top element of the stack, but it’s ephemeral (volatile).

Answer (score 16):

For **bash**, basically: instead of using cd one can use `pushd` to change directories. With practical usage: the history of visited directories is saved (correctly: stacked) and one can switch between them:

```
pushd /home; pushd /var; pushd /tmp
```

To see the stack use `dirs` and for easier navigation (to get the numbers of the "stack-entries" use:

```
dirs -v
```

Output:

```
me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
 0  /home
 1  /var
 2  /tmp
```

Now utilize these numbers with `cd` and `~` like:

```
cd ~1
```

But these numbers are rearranged now and position "0" will change, so just `pushd` the directory to the top position twice (or use a dummy on position 0) like:

```
me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
 0  /home
 1  /home
 2  /var
 3  /tmp
```

Now 1..3 will keep their position

(To release the current directory from the stack/deleting it from history, use `popd`)

Answer (score 14):

`pushd` and `popd` allow you to manipulate the directories on stack.

When you `pushd` a directory, you put the current directory on the stack and change directory to the one specified as a parameter.

`popd` will allow you to go back to the directory on the stack.

If you repeat, the directory traversal will be sort of preserved and you can come back to the saved directories in reverse order from what you saved them in.

Answer (score 7):

I found the usage of dirs/popd/pushd a bit uncomfortable. I came up with my personal solution in tcsh, by addind the following code into .alias

```
  foreach b (. , - 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 )
    alias p$b       'set a=`pwd`; echo $a >! ~/.mydir'$b
    alias cd$b      'cd "`cat ~/.mydir'$b'`"'
    alias del$b     'rm -v ~/.mydir'$b
    alias home$b    'set a="~"; echo $a >! ~/.mydir'$b
  end
    alias cdl       'grep / ~/.mydir*'
```

in this way I aliased, for instance, "p." to save the current working  dir into file ~/.mydir. and "cd." to recover that dir whenever and wherever I like.
"del." removes the corresponding file; "home." sets the dir to the home dir (equivalent to cd; p. ); "cdl" lists what are the saved dirs.
Note that if you use ~/Dropbox/.mydir$b (or any other cloud service like e.g. ownCloud) instead of ~/.mydir$b you get a smart way to use your preferred dirs across different accounts and machines.

Answer (score 6):

Simply put, when you need to navigate between more than 2 directories, usually several times back & forth, as `cd -` just won't cut it with anything beyond 2 folders.

So, for example, instead of trying to re-come up with previous long paths by looking at your buffer's history or tab-completing a long pathway you simply stack the important ones up and if needed you conveniently move to them by their number alone. Rotating between complex directories structures and long paths becomes slick and swift.

The builtins also allow you to re-order the stack or pop out the directories you don't need anymore allowing flexibility in your workflow.

Directories stacking can also be used in scripts similarly for operations that span several directories.

Answer (score 5):

Using `cd` and `cd -` allows you to toggle between only your two most recently used directories. Your "directory working set" size is two.

Using `pushd`, you can keep an arbitrarily large number of directories in your working set.

I use `pushd` most of the time rather than `cd`. Once you've built up a stack of active directories with `pushd directory_name`, you can then jump between them all day with `pushd ~#`.

```
pushd dir1
pushd ../dir2
pushd /full/path/to/dir3

# There are now three directories in the stack.

pushd ~3
pushd ~2

# The same three directories are still on the stack, 
# just in a different order.
```

I use `popd` rarely, only when I want to remove a directory from the stack when I know I'm done using that directory.

Go to directory and remove it from the stack:

```
popd ~2
```

Stay in current directory and remove another directory from the stack:

```
popd +2
```

You end up with a working style that is similar to having multiple terminal windows or tabs open (one for each directory in which you're actively working), but all in one terminal. This saves screen real estate, plus, because the directory paths are all available in one shell, you can do things like:

- copy files between directories you are currently working with
- view or edit files in another directory without going there

Examples:

```
cp ~2/myfile.txt ~4
less ~2/myfile.txt
```

---

In `tcsh` (but not `bash`), you can even save your directory stack to a file and restore it later.

Save:

```
dirs -S ~/dirstack
```

Restore:

```
dirs -L ~/dirstack
```

Otherwise, just replace `~` in the `bash` examples with `=` for use in `tcsh`.

```
pushd =2
popd =4
popd +1
```

Answer (score 3):

> I am using it like this  in my bash_profile and .bashrc like this

```
vi .bash_profile
alias dirs="dirs -v"
source d.sh
:wq

vi .bashrc
alias dirs="dirs -v"
:wq

vi d.sh
pushd ~/Documents/GIT/seiso-data
pushd ~/Documents/GIT/ewe/EosRegistry
pushd ~/Documents/GIT_LODGING/site-cookbooks
pushd ~/Documents/CHEF_LODGING
pushd  .
:wq
```

**it helps me jump in between directories to most recent used on my terminal.** :-) Hope it helps you to use pushd rather popd i use cd ~stackednumber

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/python3/appendix-a-cli/ex8.html) nice explanation:

> The `pushd` command takes your current directory and "pushes" it into a list for later, then it changes to another directory. It's like saying, "Save where I am, then go here."

> The `popd` command takes the last directory you pushed and "pops" it off, taking you back there.