# Do we have more history for cd?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, cd-command, pushd

`cd -` can move to the last visited directory. Can we visit more history other than the last one?

Comment: [Meta discussion about this question's tags](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3352/are-really-valid-questions-that-can-have-both-shell-and-bash-zsh-tcsh)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `pushd` and `popd`.

You could view a practical working example of `pushd` and `popd` from [here](http://linux.101hacks.com/cd-command/dirs-pushd-popd/).

```
mkdir /tmp/dir1
mkdir /tmp/dir2
mkdir /tmp/dir3
mkdir /tmp/dir4

cd /tmp/dir1
pushd .

cd /tmp/dir2
pushd .

cd /tmp/dir3
pushd .

cd /tmp/dir4
pushd .

dirs
/tmp/dir4 /tmp/dir4 /tmp/dir3 /tmp/dir2 /tmp/dir1
```

Comment: There's also `$OLDPWD` in case you want to flip back and forth between two directories using the same command, but I'm unsure how shell-specific and distribution/kernel-specific this is.

Comment: @ivy_lynx `OLDPWD` exists in all POSIX shells, but it's useless for this question which asks how to go beyond that (the question already mentions `cd -` which is a shortcut for `cd "$OLDPWD"`).

Comment: Is there a reason you use `cd /tmp/dir1; pushd .`  instead of just `pushd /tmp/dir1`?

Comment: @gnp, no specific reason. It was just taken from the link that I have referred to in the answer. `pushd /tmp/dir1` should work just fine.

Comment: Ok, just picked my curiosity. I'd like to suggest you improve your answer with an actual example using `pushd` and `popd` to traverse a directory tree back and forth. Your answer is already the correct one.

Answer (score 87):

You didn't specify which shell you are using, so let this be excuse to advertise zsh.

Yes, we do have more history for `cd`, namely `cd -2`, `cd -4` etc. Very convenient is `cd -`<kbd>TAB</kbd>, especially with completion system and colors enabled:

This is what I have in .zshrc:

```
setopt AUTO_PUSHD                  # pushes the old directory onto the stack
setopt PUSHD_MINUS                 # exchange the meanings of '+' and '-'
setopt CDABLE_VARS                 # expand the expression (allows 'cd -2/tmp')
autoload -U compinit && compinit   # load + start completion
zstyle ':completion:*:directory-stack' list-colors '=(#b) #([0-9]#)*( *)==95=38;5;12'
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: bash  bash bash bash

Comment: OK, I won't delete this answer, maybe will be useful for others.

Comment: Unless the question specifically asks about `bash`, this is a valid answer. Don't remove it.

Comment: What if the OP edits his question to include bash only, will this answer still  be valid?

Comment: Nice feature, didn't know this about zsh.

Comment: @Ooker that's discussed in detail somewhere on meta.SO or meta.SE, but in this case I would say yes because it's still very useful, and even worthwhile to say "this feature *could* be implemented because it exists here."

Comment: It might bear mentioning that apart from `setopt AUTO_PUSHD`, none of the above setup is *required* to get an omnipresent directory stack with completion in stock zsh. `PUSHD_MINUS` reverses the sense of `cd +` and `cd -` (a matter of taste), `CDABLE_VARS` is irrelevant to directory stacks, and the `zstyle` invocation given here simply adds colouring to the output of a directory stack completion. One must however initialise the completion subsystem with `autoload -U compinit && compinit`.

Comment: Great! I didn't know about this specific feature of zsh! Thanks a lot for the hint! +1

Comment: Thanks @jimmy, for not deleting that answer. Nearly a decade later I found it very useful.

Answer (score 14):

To answer your question regarding "more history". No the `cd -` feature in Bash only supports a single directory that you can "flip" back to. As @Ramesh states in his answer. If you want a longer history of directories you can use `pushd` and `popd` to save a directory or return to a previous one.

You can also see the list of what's currently in the stack with the `dirs` command.

A detailed explanation can be found from this answer titled: [How do I use pushd and popd commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77077/how-do-i-use-pushd-and-popd-commands).

Comment: I have included a reference from your answer. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @Ramesh - nope go ahead.

Answer (score 11):

You can install and use my [dirhistory](https://github.com/madsen/dirhistory) utility for bash.

Basically, it's a daemon that collects directory changes from all your shells, and a Cdk program that displays the history and lets you pick any directory to switch to (so you're not limited to a stack).

Answer (score 8):

You have as much history as you want:

```
cd() {
[ "$((${DIRSTACKMAX##*[!0-9]*}0/10))" -gt 0 ] &&
        set -- "$@" "$DIRSTACK"               &&
        DIRSTACK='pwd -P >&3; command cd'     ||
        { command cd "$@"; return; }
_q()    while   case "$1" in (*\'*) :   ;;      (*)
                ! DIRSTACK="$DIRSTACK '$2$1'"   ;;esac
        do      set -- "${1#*\'}" "$2${1%%\'*}'\''"
        done
while   [ "$#" -gt 1 ]
do      case    ${1:---} in (-|[!-]*|-*[!0-9]*) : ;;
        (*)     eval "  set $((${1#-}+1))"' "${'"$#}\""
                eval '  set -- "$2"'" $2"'
                        set -- "${'"$1"'}" "$1"'
        ;;esac; _q "$1"; shift
done
eval "  DIRSTACK=; $DIRSTACK    &&"'
        _q "$OLDPWD"            &&
        DIRSTACK=$DIRSTACK\ $1
        set "$?" "${DIRSTACK:=$1}"'" $1
"       3>/dev/null
[ "$(($#-1))" -gt "$DIRSTACKMAX" ] &&
        DIRSTACK="${DIRSTACK% \'/*}"
unset -f _q; return "$1"
}
```

That's a shell function that should enable any POSIX compatible shell to offer `zsh`-style `cd` history. It does all of its work without invoking a single subshell, and I believe its flow is pretty sound - it seems to handle all cases correctly under moderate testing.

The function attempts to play as nicely with its environment as it may while still relying on fully portable syntax - it makes only one assumption and that is that the `$DIRSTACK` environment variable is its property to do with as it will.

It canonicalizes all paths that it stores in `$DIRSTACK` and serializes all of them on single-quotes - though it ensures each is safely quoted and serialized before adding it to the value of the variable and shouldn't have any issue with any special characters of any kind. If the `$DIRSTACKMAX` environment variable is set it will use it as an upper limit for the number of paths it retains in history, else the limit is one.

If you load the function you just `cd` as normal but will also be able to do the `cd -[num]` for retracing back through your change directory history.

The function's primary mechanism is `cd` itself - and the `${OLD,}PWD` environment variables. POSIX specifies that `cd` change these for every path move - and so this just uses the shell's builtin variables and saves the values for as long as you like.

Comment: @datUser - i knew someone had a dat. youre quite welcome

Answer (score 4):

The [acd_func.sh](http://linuxgazette.net/109/marinov.html) script does exactly what you describe. Essentially it overloads the `cd` function and enables you to type `cd --` to get a list of previously visited directories, from which you can select by number. I find it very hard to use bash without this anymore, and its the first thing I install on a new system.

Comment: https://github.com/djoot/all-bash-history/blob/master/acd_func.sh

Answer (score 3):

Others already covered some interesting solutions. Some time ago I created my own solution to a related problem that could be quickly modified to do "straight history". I basically wanted to "label" a few commonly used directories, and wanted *all* open shells to see them, and for them to persist between reboots.

```
#dir_labels
#functions to load and retrieve list of dir aliases

function goto_complete {
    unset dir_labels
    declare -A dir_labels
    {
    while read line; do
        ll_pre="${line%% *}"
        ll_dir="${line#* }"
        dir_labels["$ll_pre"]="$ll_dir"
    done
    } < ~/.dir_labels
    unset ll_pre
    unset ll_dir

    local cur possib
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    possib="${!dir_labels[@]}"
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${possib}" -- ${cur}) )
}

complete -F goto_complete goto

function goto {
    unset dir_labels
    declare -A dir_labels
    {
    while read line; do
        ll_pre="${line%% *}"
        ll_dir="${line#* }"
        dir_labels["$ll_pre"]="$ll_dir"
    done
    } < ~/.dir_labels
    unset ll_pre
    unset ll_dir

    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    key="$1"
    else
    key=default
    fi
    target="${dir_labels[$key]}"
    if [ -d "$target" ]; then
    cd "$target"
    echo "goto $key: '$target'"
    else
    echo "directory '$target' does not exist"
    fi
}

function label {
    unset dir_labels
    declare -A dir_labels
    {
    while read line; do
        ll_pre="${line%% *}"
        ll_dir="${line#* }"
        dir_labels["$ll_pre"]="$ll_dir"
    done
    } < ~/.dir_labels
    unset ll_pre
    unset ll_dir

    if [ $# -gt 0 ]; then
    target="$1"
    else
    target="default"
    fi
    dir_labels["$target"]=$PWD
    for i in "${!dir_labels[@]}"; do
    echo "$i ${dir_labels[$i]}"
    done > ~/.dir_labels
}
```

Basically I'd just do `label foo` to call the current directory `foo`, and then from whatever shell, `goto foo` whould `cd` directly there. Empty argument: `label` would create a default target for `goto`.

I didn't bother implementing automated removal of aliases, but otherwise, I'm still using this in a slightly modified form.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my "cd history" function from
http://fex.belwue.de/fstools/bash.html

It remembers every directory where you have been and with "cdh" you will see a
list of the last 9 directories. Just enter the number and you are back in
this directory.

Example:

```
framstag@wupp:/: cdh
1: /usr/local/bin
2: /var
3: /
4: /tmp/135_pana/1280
5: /tmp/135_pana
6: /tmp/weihnachtsfeier
7: /tmp
8: /local/home/framstag
select: 4
framstag@wupp:/tmp/135_pana/1280:
```

cdh works with autocd aka "cd without cd": you do not have to type cd
or pushd.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to recommend my extended 'cd' function to you:

https://github.com/dczhu/ltcd

[image]

It provides the following features to make life easier:

- Global dir listing, which shows recently visited dirs from all terminal tabs/windows.
- Local dir listing, which is local to current shell session.
- Both listings support quick navigation by using j/k (go down/up), numbers, and word searching.
- Global free jumping (e.g. "cd dir" or "cd ar" to go to /path/to/foo/bar/directory/).

Comment: Hm, looks promising. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

for **bash**, basically: instead of using cd use `pushd` to change directorys, so they are saved (meaning stacked)

```
pushd /home; pushd /var; pushd log
```

To see the stack use `dirs` and for easier navigation (to get the numbers of the "stack-entries" use:

```
dirs -v
```

Output:

```
me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
 0  /home
 1  /var
 2  /tmp
```

Now utilize these numbers with `cd` and `~` like:

```
cd ~1
```

But now these numbers are rearranged now and position "0" will change, so just `pushd` the directory to the top position twice (or use a dummy on position 0) like:

```
me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
 0  /home
 1  /home
 2  /var
 3  /tmp
```

now 1..3 will keep there position
*I read this somewhere but do not know anymore, so sorry for not giving credit*

(to release the current directory from the stack/deleting it from history use `popd`)

Answer (score 1):

See the cdh function in "Shell Programming, 4e" on page 312.  It keeps the history in an array.

Here's a more advanced version: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4f-lR6inxQWQ1pPZVpUQ3FSZ2M

It Stores the history in the file CDHISTFILE and allows changing to the most recent directory that contains a string, e.g.,

`cd -src`

It installs itself over the existing cd command by doing an `alias cd=_cd`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the answer @mikeserv gave, but it didn't quite work for me. I couldn't figure out how to fix it, so I just wrote my own:

```
cd() {
    # Set the current directory to the 0th history item
    cd_history[0]=$PWD
    if [[ $1 == -h ]]; then
        for i in ${!cd_history[@]}; do
            echo $i: "${cd_history[$i]}"
        done
        return
    elif [[ $1 =~ ^-[0-9]+ ]]; then
        builtin cd "${cd_history[${1//-}]}" || # Remove the argument's dash
        return 
    else
        builtin cd "$@" || return # Bail if cd fails
    fi
    # cd_history = ["", $OLDPWD, cd_history[1:]]
    cd_history=("" "$OLDPWD" "${cd_history[@]:1:${#cd_history[@]}}")
}
```

This is also available as a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/saagarjha/f9e9186479975d36dc18b15a87849205). To use this, just paste the function into your `.bashrc` or similar, and you'll be able to do things like `cd -5` to go back to the 5<sup>th</sup> last directory you've been in. `cd -h` will give you an overview of your history.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add [fzf-marks](https://github.com/urbainvaes/fzf-marks) as a possible solution.

Once installed it gives you the commands **mark** and **jump** to add and search for bookmarked directories (yes, the it's not exactly the complete history, only the ones you bookmarked yourself).

The problem I have with pushd/popd it session specific behaviour, i.e. I'd like to have the same stack on different bash session or so which is possible for fzf-marks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own [cdhist](https://github.com/bulletmark/cdhist) tool for this about 16 years ago and have used it all day every day since. It replaces your `cd` command with an alias which keeps track of the directories you visit so that you can `cd --` to list them and then select one. It also [integrates with fzf](https://github.com/bulletmark/cdhist#fzf-integration) if you prefer to fuzzy search over previously visited directories.

Answer (score 0):

here another implementation, history and also locate usage:
https://github.com/joknarf/cdhist
(compatible ksh / bash / zsh / ash shells linux* / macos / ish / msys2 / implementation...)

[image: cdhist in action]

After sourcing cdhist in your shell you will get extended cd command to add history of all visited directories (saved in file, which means will remains after shell session closed) and search/choose directory from history.

### cd command alias

- cdhist aliases cd command to function that will push cd history to file.
  by default history saved to ~/.cd_history

  - CDHISTFILE environment variable can be used to override default
- changing current working dir using cd will add directory to $CDHISTFILE
- calling `cd --` without option will display last $CDNBDIRS (default 10) visited directories, number or `<pattern>` can be used to change dir/refilter list
- calling `cd -- [<pattern> ...]` will search for regexp `<pattern>.*[<pattern>]...` in $CDHISTFILE.

  - if found and unique will directory change to this directory
  - if multiple matches, will display directories list to choose the one to cd

    - can choose directory by number
    - or give another `<pattern>` to refilter result
- calling `cd - <pattern> ...` will change to last directory in $CDHISTFILE that is matching patterns
- `cd-` is alias for `cd -`
- `cd--` is alias for `cd --`

### cdlocate

- `cdlocate` function (alias `cdl`) uses `locate` command (mlocate or plocate) to search for directories
- `cdl <pattern> [<pattern>...]` to search for directories match in locate db (dot directories like .git excluded)

  - if match found and unique change to directory
  - if not unique displays list of found matching directories

    - choose directory to change using number
    - or give pattern to filter result for another list

code: (compatibility with bash/ksh/zsh/ash)

```bash
unalias cd 2>/dev/null # avoid re-entrance
type typeset >/dev/null 2>/dev/null || alias typeset=local # ash no typeset
touch ${CDHISTFILE:=~/.cd_history}

# change directory and updpate CDHISTFILE
function cdpush {
    typeset cdhf=${CDHISTFILE:-~/.cd_history}
    case "$1" in 
        --) shift; cdhist "$@"; return $?;;
        -)  [ "$2" ] && { cdhist "$@"; return $?; };;
        ~*) set -- "$HOME${1#\~}";;
    esac
    \cd "$@" || return $?
    echo "$PWD" >"$cdhf.tmp"
    grep -v "^$PWD$" "$cdhf" >>"$cdhf.tmp"
    [ -s "$cdhf.tmp" ] && \mv "$cdhf.tmp" "$cdhf"
    return 0
}

function cdselect
{
    typeset dirs="$1" resp
    while true
    do
        [ "$dirs" ] || return 1
        [[ "$dirs" != *$'\n'* ]] && { cdpush "$dirs" ; return $?; }
        echo "$dirs"| GREP_COLORS='ms=01;34' GREP_COLOR='1;34;49' grep --color=auto -n ".*" 2>/dev/null
        printf "cd: "
        read resp
        case "$resp" in
            '')       break;;
            *[!0-9]*) dirs=$(echo "$dirs" |egrep "$resp" 2>/dev/null);;
            *)        cdpush "$(echo "$dirs" |awk NR==$resp)"; return $?;;
        esac
    done
}

# cdhist    : Display CDNBDIRS history
# cdhist -a : whole history
# cdhist [-a] <pattern> [<pat>...]: display dirs matching pattern/cd to dir if unique found
function cdhist {
    typeset gr=. nb=${CDNBDIRS:-10} cdhf=${CDHISTFILE:-~/.cd_history} first='' awk=awk dir
    [ ! -s "$cdhf" ] && echo "$CDINITDIRS" >$cdhf
    [ "$1" = -a ] && nb=-1 && shift
    [ "$1" = - ] && first="exit" && shift
    [ -x /bin/nawk ] && awk=nawk
    [ "$1" ] && gr=$($awk 'BEGIN{OFS=".*";for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++) $i=ARGV[i];print}' "$@")
    cdselect "$($awk 'n == nb {exit} $0 == pwd {next} $0 ~ gr {n++;sub("^"hom,"~");print;'$first'}' gr="$gr" pwd="$PWD" nb=$nb hom=$HOME $cdhf)"
}


# use locate to get directories
function locatedir {
    typeset file gr awk=awk
    [ "$1" ] || return
    [ -x /bin/nawk ] && awk=nawk
    gr=$($awk 'BEGIN{OFS=".*";for(i=1;i<ARGC;i++) $i=ARGV[i];print}' "$@")
    shift $(($# - 1))
    locate -r "$gr" |awk -F'/' '/\/\./{next}$NF ~ gr' gr=${1##*/} |while read file
    do
        [ -d "$file" ] && echo "$file"
    done
}

function cdlocate {
    cdselect "$(locatedir "$@")"
}

alias cd=cdpush
alias cd-='cd -'
alias cd--=cdhist
alias cdl=cdlocate
```

github link has also `cd +` and `cd ++` extension to navigate through subdirectories of current dir.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/447752)

Comment: I agree with !Philoppos. Is `cd --` the main point that this animation demonstrates? Then say so in your answer and explain in text what it does without relying on the animation..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).