# How to see and use the last paths used in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, path

I'm quite a newbe. I was wandering: is it possible to see the last paths used in terminal (bash, whatever.., I use a Mac), something like what you do with recent commands?

I often use the terminal on the same paths (generally the same project)  for several days. To me, it's quite annoying to search for the same path every morning when I open the terminal.

Comment: Or http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157763/70524, depending on how you look at it

Comment: You could add an alias wich prints out the needed path. Or you could add an alias for a complete command with which uses the appropriate path.

Comment: strart by 1) up-arrow  -- to go back in history; 2) `CTR-R` to interactive search in history;

Answer (score 2):

If you have history set up, you can use

```
history | grep cd
```

to see your recent `cd` commands. 
You should be able to use them to figure out where you were working last time.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to change into a certain directory each time you open a shell? In this case you can add the `cd` command to your `~/.bashrc` (or the appropriate `rc` file for your shell if you don't use `bash`).

Another approach would be to create an alias in `~/.bash_aliases`, e. g.

```
alias pd='cd /my/project/dir'
```

and enter `pd` each time you want to get there.