# Terminal: remember working directory

Tags: terminal

I have git repos stored in different directories which have long paths `/opt/too/long/path/to/type/every/time/git-repo` and it's kind of difficult to remember plus to `cd` to the directory every time is a pain and tedious. (I know <kbd>TAB</kbd> helps but that gets tedious too.) So, my life would be much easier if I could store the `pwd` somewhere and later do something like `cd thatgitrepo`.

Comment: Why not using alias?

Comment: or symbolic links in your home directory?

Comment: @cuongnv Alias works. Didn't know about it. Thanks. :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I shorten the typing needed to `cd` into some well know directories](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/97312/22003).

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the question suggested by @danielAzuelos, not the one in the masthead. But the best solution imho *is* to [use `CDPATH`](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238170/60998). It has many advantages over symlinks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make yourself some symbolic links in your home directory:

```
ln -s /opt/really/long/obnoxiously/long/path/to/some/projectname
```

This command will make a link called `projectname` in your home directory into which you can `cd`, and everything will work perfectly.

Answer (score 15):

[`z`](https://github.com/rupa/z/) is a very nice "plugin" for `bash` or `zsh` (it's included in [Oh My Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/)) which keeps track of directories you `cd` to, and allows you to quickly switch to directories using parts of their names, based on how frequently you use them.

So after a little while, it will know that

```
z git-repo
```

should `cd` to the `git-repo` directory you use most often. You can qualify that with part of the path, *e.g.*

```
z d git-repo
```

or even

```
z d git
```

I've found this to be more useful than aliases or even `CDPATH` because it learns on its own and adapts to my changing habits.

Answer (score 10):

Once inside the directory, you do:

```
repo=`pwd`
```

and later you do

```
cd $repo
```

If you want to keep it for next time, you could do:

```
echo "export repo=`pwd`" >> ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 9):

`bash`'s `CDPATH` shell variable might be a convenient solution for you. A command such as `cd foo` searches for the subdirectory called `foo` inside the directories listed in `CDPATH`.

Answer (score 8):

Just to mention another useful tool, there is the `pushd` builtin. With

```
$ pushd dirname
```

the current directory will be pushed on the directory stack (you can look at that stack with `dirs`) and the current directory will be changed to `dirname`. You can later change back to the latest (top-most in the stack) directory using the `popd` builtin command.

This should work at least in bash, zsh, csh and tcsh.

If you just want to change to the previous directory you have been in, `cd -` comes to help.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it; create an alias in `~/.bashrc` (if using Bash):

```
alias thatgitrepo='cd /opt/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/git-repo'
```

And use `source .bashrc` to have the alias for the current shell.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157763/15654) by [ramesh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/47538/ramesh):

> The command you are looking for is `pushd` and `popd`.
>
> You could view a practical working example of `pushd` and `popd` from [here](http://linux.101hacks.com/cd-command/dirs-pushd-popd/).
>
> ```
> mkdir /tmp/dir1
> mkdir /tmp/dir2
> mkdir /tmp/dir3
> mkdir /tmp/dir4
>
> cd /tmp/dir1
> pushd .
>
> cd /tmp/dir2
> pushd .
>
> cd /tmp/dir3
> pushd .
>
> cd /tmp/dir4
> pushd .
>
> dirs
> /tmp/dir4 /tmp/dir4 /tmp/dir3 /tmp/dir2 /tmp/dir1
> ```

Comment: You can also just do `pushd /some/new/dir`.

Comment: If using zsh, `setopt autopushd` makes every `cd` a `pushd`, which is fantastic in that you no longer have to remember to use a different command.

Answer (score 0):

For coding stuff I have always just used environment variables to store commonly used code directories.

In a bash file that gets executed do:

```
export PROJECTNAMEDIR=/opt/too/long/path/to/type/every/time/git-repo
```

Then you can do stuff like `cd $PROJECTNAMEDIR` or `git checkout $PROJECTNAMEDIR` and also variables will autocomplete with bash.

Comment: A great answer!  Except...  largely redundant with [Julie Pelletier's already-existing answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/282922/97078).

Comment: Haha fair enough, didn't see that one, just upvoted now.