# cd 3 times to great-grandparent dir

Tags: cd-command, dirname

I have this:

```
cd $(dirname $(dirname $(dirname "$0"))) &&
```

which will cd to project root.

Is there shorthand for this somehow, where I can just be like:

```
cd 3 &&  # not quite, but you get the idea
```

or whatever, I mean why not you know?

Maybe a command like so would be ideal:

```
cdx 3 &&
```

since `cd` has no idea that 3 is not a file or directory.

Comment: What's this supposed to do? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Using [pushd, popd and dirs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/270437/235424) to navigate directories is the most useful shorthand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *do* know that `cd ..` takes you to the parent directory? So, if I understand your question correctly, you could use:

```
cd $(dirname $0)/../../..
```

Comment: should it be: `cd "$0/../../.."` (with quotes)

Comment: this is much better than what I have

Comment: This is not equivalent in all cases. `cd -P` and `cd -L` may give different results. If way not work at all: if d1 exists but d1/d2/d3/d4 does not.

Comment: That won't work because `$0` is not a directory. You need to call `dirname` or do string processing to extract the directory part of `$0`.

Answer (score 1):

Define this function:

```
dirx(){ a=$0;for((i=0;i<$1;i++));do a=${a%/*};done;cd "$a"; }
```

And do:

```
$ dirx 3
```

Comment: This only works if `$0` contains sufficiently many path components, not if it's just `bar` or `foo/bar`.

Comment: @Gilles It fails gracefully to the string provided. If it is just bar, it results on `cd bar`. If bar doesn't exist, it provides a clear error mesage: `bash: cd: bar: No such file or directory`. What is not robust enought for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameter expansion in `bash`:

```
cd "${0%/*/*/*}"
```

or even simpler in `zsh`:

```
cd $0:h:h:h
```

Comment: This only works if `$0` contains sufficiently many path components, not if it's just `bar` or `foo/bar`.