# dirs -v does not list the directory stack?

Tags: bash, directory, alias, shell-builtin, pushd

I have seen [How do I use pushd and popd commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77077/how-do-i-use-pushd-and-popd-commands) , and I am aware that with `pushd <dir>` I would push `<dir>` to the directory stack, with `popd` I would pop the top directory from the directory stack - and with `dirs -v` I should be viewing/listing the directory stack; the cited post gives this example:

> ```
> $ pushd /home; pushd /var; pushd log
>
> me@myhost:/home$ dirs -v
>  0  /home
>  1  /var
>  2  /tmp
> ```

So, I'm on:

```
$ echo $(cat /etc/issue; lsb_release -idcr); uname -a; bash --version | head -1
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS Release: 14.04 Codename: trusty
Linux MyPC 4.4.0-104-generic #127~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:44:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

And I'm doing this test in a `bash` terminal:

```
user@PC:~$ cd /tmp/
user@PC:tmp$ dirs -v                                            ## just lists, no directory stack
total 32
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Jan  5 18:22 MozillaMailnews/
prwxrwxr-x 1 user user    0 Jan  6 11:54 SciTE.22933.in|
-rw------- 1 user user    0 Jan  4 12:07 config-err-pY6fcB
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Jan  6 00:55 firefox_user/
-rw------- 1 user user  275 Jan  6 12:07 h
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Jan  5 15:43 mozilla_user0/
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Jan  6 02:11 mozilla_mozillaUser0/
drwx------ 3 user user 4096 Jan  5 10:28 sni-qt_vlc_19957-mFfsIO/
drwx------ 2 user user 4096 Jan  4 12:07 ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb/
drwx------ 6 root          root          4096 Jan  4 12:07 systemd-generator.yBhsiB/

user@PC:tmp$ pushd /tmp/ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb/
/tmp/ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb /tmp
user@PC:ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb$ dirs -v                               ## again, just lists, no directory stack
total 0
srw------- 1 user user 0 Jan  4 12:07 agent.1477=

user@PC:ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb$ pushd /tmp/sni-qt_vlc_19957-mFfsIO/
/tmp/sni-qt_vlc_19957-mFfsIO /tmp/ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb /tmp
user@PC:sni-qt_vlc_19957-mFfsIO$ dirs -v                        ## again, just lists, no directory stack
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Jan  5 10:28 icons/

user@PC:sni-qt_vlc_19957-mFfsIO$ popd
/tmp/ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb /tmp
user@PC:ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb$ dirs -v                               ## again, just lists, no directory stack
total 0
srw------- 1 user user 0 Jan  4 12:07 agent.1477=
user@PC:ssh-Ry3s5LesiOrb$ popd
/tmp
```

As you can see from this snippet, in the test I **never** got `dirs -v` to list/print the directory *stack* - it simply lists the files in the current directory similar to `ls` ?!

So, how can I get `dirs -v` to show/print/list the directory stack? Alternatively, is there another command I could use to show/print/list the directory stack in a `bash` terminal?

Comment: Show output of `type dirs`.

Comment: Thanks @Cyrus - since it's small, I'll post it in this comment: `$ type dirs` -> `dirs is aliased to 'ls -lFS --color'`, so I get it now: `grep dirs ~/.bashrc` shows the alias is defined in `~/.bashrc`; must I edit the `~/.bashrc`, or is there another way to take care of this temporarily in the current `bash` session? Btw, feel free to post as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can also ignore this alias with a leading backslash at bash's prompt: `\dirs -v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment out the alias line in your `~/.bashrc` with a `#`.

In your current session you can use `unalias dirs` to remove this alias. Check again with `type dirs`.

Comment: Many thanks, @Cyrus - I also found that `bash -c 'dirs -v'` in the aliased session will also call the proper `dirs` (probably because in that subshell, the `~/.bashrc` would not be read at all)

Comment: Yes, bash reads `~/.bashrc` only if it is an interactive shell.